# Pareto Front for Optimisation

Tags: python, pandas, optimization

I have a dataset as such:

```
import pandas as pd
Data = {'N':[106, 193, 87, 206, 32, 275, 14, 154, 55, 53],
        'M':[25, 250, 100, 82, 17, 162, 8, 148, 6, 100],
        'P':[131, 443, 187, 288, 48, 437, 22, 301, 61, 153],
        'C':[0.20, 0.07, 0.03, 0.78, 0.80, 0.55, 0.83, 0.10, 0.15, 0.05],
        'E':[-2.02, -1.59, -4.26, -0.32, -0.55, -0.77, -0.13, -1.34, -1.99, -2.89]
        }
df = pd.DataFrame (Data, columns = ['N','M','P','C','E'])
```

Initially I was looking to calculate a vector of values X which would maximise the equation:

```
df["R"] = (df["P"] * df["C"] * df["X"] ) + (df["M"] * df["C"] * df["E"] * df["X"] ) + (df["P"] * df["C"] * df["E"] * df["X"]* df["X"] )
```

One vector of X values I have found via differentiation in excel that maximised the above equation is:

```
X = pd.DataFrame({'X': [0.15, 0.03, -0.15, 1.44, 0.74, 0.46, 3.70, 0.13, 0.21, -0.15]})
df = df.join(X)
```

However whilst this maximises the value of R for each of the rows, another equation I need to consider is the mean value of C_N as per the equation:

```
df["C_N"] =  df["C"] + (df["C"] * df["E"] * df["X"])  
df.loc['Average Metrics'] = df.mean() 
df.loc['Sum Metrics'] = df[:-1].sum()
```

With these set of X values the mean value for C_N across the rows is 0.217774 and the sum of R is 231.707.

Am looking to:

1. Plot what the maximum value of the sum of R would be for each of the mean C_N values between 0 to 1 (i.e. a Pareto Optimal Front).
2. For each of the points on that front (i.e. non-dominated points on the frontier) I would like tobe able to find out the vector of X values that were used.

Any help towards this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Sounds like you might want to use a regression library so you don't have to calculate `X` by hand.  Check out things like [`statsmodels`](https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/generated/statsmodels.regression.linear_model.OLS.html) to do the regression and [`patsy`](https://patsy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/API-reference.html) to build the input for the regression from a formula specification.  (Obviously this is a huge topic so this is just one possible direction.)

Comment: i know (a little) pareto front, but i dont understant your environment, the link of what you do and pareto, could you precise the ouput you want. why are you using this equation PCX + MCEX + PCEXX